# Traceback (most recent call last): error seen on running python file in Pycharm

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/IPT-Autobot/mybot.py", line 3, in 
    import slack
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slack'

No code changed were made , but i did some mess up with interpreter settings after which i feel i started getting the error

Here is the code

```
import os
import re
import slack
import logging
import string
from subprocess import check_output
import datetime

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    try:
        ##0 get clients and payload
        logging.info('msg received')
        data = payload['data']
        web_client = payload['web_client']
        rtm_client = payload['rtm_client']

        ##0 - 1 Check if it is the first msg, not replied msg by me
        #print(data)
        if data.get('text') == None:
            logging.info('This msg is my replied msg.')
            return False
        ##0-2 Get channel info
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']
        user = data['user']

        ##1 get scenario submsg
        msg = data['text']
        retVal = analysis_msg(msg)
        # print(retVal)
        if retVal == False:
            retMsg = "This message is not for testing. Please check the message format.\nFEATURE_ID:SKU:FULFILLMENT"
            send_msg(web_client, channel_id, thread_ts, user, retMsg)
            return False

        ##2 form cmd
        retVal = form_cmd(retVal)
        print(retVal)
        if retVal == False:
            return False

        ##3 execute cmd
        #inform the start of test
        retMsg = "Testing is going on.... Please wait for the result."
        send_msg(web_client, channel_id, thread_ts, user, retMsg)
        try:
            res1 = check_output(retVal, shell=True).decode()
            res = reg_result(res1)
            if res == False:
                res = "The test scenario has no correct result."
        except  Exception as ee:
            res = "The test scenario has a failure. Please Check the feature file."

        ## 4 send result to slack
        retMsg = "The result is here.\n" + res
        create_result_file(user, res)
        send_msg(web_client, channel_id, thread_ts, user, retMsg)
        print(retVal)



    except Exception as e:
        print("error")
        logging.critical(str(e))

############################    My handlers     ##############################
def create_result_file(user, res):
    try:
        cur_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_name = user + str(cur_time.year)  + str(cur_time.month)  + str(cur_time.day)  + str(cur_time.hour)   + str(cur_time.minute)   + str(cur_time.second) + '.txt'
        file = open(file_name,'w')
        file.write(res)
        file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
def send_msg(web_client, channel_id, thread_ts, user, mgs):
    web_client.chat_postMessage(
        channel=channel_id,
        text=f"Hi <@{user}>! \n " + mgs,
        thread_ts=thread_ts
    )
#error code mgmt.   !   reserved
def error_code(code):
    #reserved
    return False

#break donw msg to the test scenario submsgs
def analysis_msg(msg):
    submsg = msg.split(":")
    if len(submsg) != 3:
        logging.warning("This msg not test scenario")
        return error_code("NOT_TEST_MSG")
    res = {}
    res["feature"] = submsg[0]
    res["sku"] = submsg[1]
    res["fulfillment"] = submsg[2]
    return res
#form cmd for test bat files    !   reserved
def form_cmd(submsg):
    #reserved
    cmd = '1.bat'
    return cmd

def reg_result(res):
    #"COP Order Response"
    lines = res.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        pattern = "COP Order Response*"
        prog = re.compile(pattern)
        result = prog.search(line)
        if result != None:
            print(result.string)
            return result.string
    return False
slack_token = "xoxb-698180291472-694969165937-zMIG1AfrYCuUgAt44Z46tIgP";#os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
rtm_client = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token)
rtm_client.start()
```

Error

```
C:\Users\A6002043\PycharmProjects\IPT-Autobot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/IPT-Autobot/mybot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/IPT-Autobot/mybot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import slack
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slack'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does `pip list` show `slack`?

Comment: Can you let me know how to check that?

Comment: go to Terminal, or Command prompt and type `pip list`

Comment: I got below result
```
Package       Version
------------- -------
aiohttp       3.5.4
async-timeout 3.0.1
attrs         19.1.0
chardet       3.0.4
idna          2.8
multidict     4.5.2
pip           19.1.1
setuptools    40.8.0
slackclient   2.1.0
yarl          1.3.0
```

Comment: It seems like you have the package available in one version of python but you are not accessing it in the version of python you are writing. Check both versions and ensure that the location of the pip packages is available to `sys.path`

Answer (score 1):

Use pip install to re-install the slack module.

```
`pip install slack client`
```

After use :

```
`from slackclient import SlackClient`
```

Had the same problem sometime ago, [this helped](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/183)

Comment: now am getting below error 

C:\Users\A6002043\PycharmProjects\slack_client_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/slack_client_python/slack_rtmClientnew.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/slack_client_python/slack_rtmClientnew.py", line 4, in <module>
    from slackclient import SlackClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: thank you , after running this `pip install slack client`  i used " from slackbot.slackclient import SlackClient"   , Error is gone

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to install tha package slack for your project:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html